# form variables and double quotes

Tags: coldfusion

I am populating form variables from a database.
If the field value has a double quote in it, such as 3" for 3 inches, then the html source looks like the following:

```
<input name="width" value="3"">
```

Q: How do I handle fields that contain double quotes?

I first thought it was a cfqueryparam problem, but it turns out it's an html problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure cfqueryparam wont remove double quotes - you probably have something else that is attempting to sanitize the data entered. Can you produce an isolated code sample that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I will setup a sample to duplicate the problem.

Comment: It is saving the double quote, but when I'm populating the form variable, the html source now looks like:
<input name="width" value="3"">

In this example, the value is 3 inches.

Comment: FYI, if you use <cfinput>, value property is automatically applied with htmlEditFormat(). :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`HtmlEditFormat`](http://cfdocs.org/htmleditformat) when displaying the value.

Like this:

```
<input name="width" value="#HtmlEditFormat(Form.Width)#" />
```

There is also:

> [`XmlFormat`](http://cfdocs.org/xmlformat) for XML output;
>   [`JsStringFormat`](http://cfdocs.org/jsstringformat) for JavaScript output;
>   [`UrlEncodedFormat`](http://cfdocs.org/urlencodedformat) for URL content.

For more complete/heavyweight stuff, you could consider [OWASP's ESAPI](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API) - a Java Security API which can be used from CF and provides the following:

```
Context        Method
-------        ------
HTML           esapi.encodeForHTML(variable)
HTML Attribute esapi.encodeForHTMLAttribute(variable)
JavaScript     esapi.encodeForJavaScript(variable)
CSS            esapi.encodeForCSS(variable)
URL            esapi.encodeForURL(variable)
```

(from [Pete Freitag's cfunited presentation slides](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/759.cfm))

Comment: D'oh!  I _knew_ I should have gone to CFUnited this year!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's probably the browser, you need to encode the quote using " in your HTML then it should pass properly.

Comment: What if I say:
<cfset form.FieldName = replace(qry.FieldName,'"','& quot;',"all")>

Will & quot; get into the database?

Comment: Better to use built-in functions that already handle this - see my answer for details.

Comment: Heh, just noticed this is you Pete - coincidentally I've just linked to your recent blog entry below. :) Slight tangent, but are you aware of this: http://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_ColdFusion_CFML_Readme - might be good to give Jason Dean and Bill Shelton a kick and get an even friendlier CF interface for ESAPI?

Comment: Hi Peter, yes I was aware of that project, but I don't know that Jason or Bill are actively working on it anymore.